# Finding slope from straight line equation

Tags: calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus

> Line $k$ lies in the $xy$-plane. The x-intercept of line $k$ is $−4$, and line
>   $k$ passes through the midpoint of the line segment whose endpoints are
>   $(2, 9)$ and $(2, 0)$. What is the slope of line $k$ ?

I understand that how to find the slope but I faced problem to get the two coordinates from the above equation. Can someone draw the picture for me then I will be able to guess the question.

Comment: Are you able to find the slope of a line if you know the coördinates of 2 distinct points lying on it?

Comment: Yes i can find that.

Comment: Then the answer of Shobhit tells you the rest. It is Always handsome to start with someting like $y=ax+b$ and then substite coördinates of points, or slope $a$ if you know it. It gives you equations in $a$ and $b$ that are quite easy to solve.

Comment: @drhab its shobhit my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x-intercept of line $k$ is $-4$ it must pass through $(-4,0)$ and the midpoint of $(2,9), (2,0) = (2, \frac92)$

Now use the two point form to find slope.

$$m = \frac{\frac92 - 0}{2-(-4)} = \frac{\frac92}6 = \frac9{12} = \frac34$$